# Mobile Server Application chat REST API

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile, application-server

I need to create a chat on my mobile application and I was looking an applications like quickblox but I need to host it on my own server for security reasons.

I would like to know if there's a product like these but installable on my server:

"really cool apps:"

- Quickblox (http://quickblox.com/)
- Scringo (http://www.scringo.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickblox can be installed on your server. 
See http://quickblox.com/enterprise/

Comment: lol ! ty very much! :D    "& can run on your servers with your / 3rd party IT team supporting it. "